# WooCommerce Create a downloadable product's order programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I use wc_create_order to create an order and everything is fine except the user can't have the downloadable product's download link in My Downloads section.

```
    $def_args = array('customer_id' => $user_id, 'status' => 'completed');
    $order = wc_create_order( $def_args );

    $targs['totals']['subtotal'] = $ord['pay_amount'];
    $targs['totals']['total'] = $ord['pay_amount'];
    $targs['totals']['subtotal_tax'] = 0;
    $targs['totals']['tax'] = 0;

    $sku_ = $ord['sku'];

    $order->add_product( get_product_by_sku( $sku_ ) , 1, $targs ); //(get_product with id and next is for quantity)
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
    $order->set_total( $ord['pay_amount'] );
    $order->calculate_totals();

    // I took get_product_by_sku function in stackoverflow but I don't remember which question. 
    function get_product_by_sku( $sku ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );

        if ( $product_id ) return new WC_Product( $product_id );

        return null;
    }
```

$ord variable has some information about the order.

Should I need to call a function or something like that to make order with download link?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, when creating an order, make the status processing and after call update_status.

```
$def_args = array('customer_id' => $user_id, 'status' => 'processing');
...
$order->update_status('completed');
```

Then user have her/his download links.